# Python BeautifulSoup - Improve readability of find by Id function?

Tags: python, string, function, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would like to improve the readability following code, especially **lines 8 to 11**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5tU8isVcqd02ymC2n952LC2Nz_FFPd6NT1lD4crDeSsJi2w/viewform?usp=sf_link'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

question1 = str(soup.find(id='i1'))
question1 = question1.split('>')[1].lstrip().split('.')[1]
question1 = question1[1:]
question1 = question1.replace("_", "")

print(question1)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by simplify? Please read [mcve]

Comment: For the variable question 1, I have redifned it a lot of times. Would it be possible to write that in 1 line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following

```
question1 = soup.find(id='i1').getText().split(".")[1].replace("_","").strip()
```

to replace lines 8 to 11.

`.getText()` takes care of removing the `html-tags`. Rest is pretty much the same.

In python you can almos always just chain operations. So your code would also be valid a a one-liner:

```
question1 = str(soup.find(id='i1')).split('>')[1].lstrip().split('.')[1][1:].replace("_", "")
```

But in most cases it is better to leave the code in a more readable form than to reduce the line-count.

Answer (score 3):

Abhinav, is not very clear what you want to achieve, the script is actually already very simple which is a good thing and follow the Pythonic principle of [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

"Simple is better than complex."

Also is not comprehensive of what you actually mean:

1. Make it more simple as in Understandable and clear for Human beings?
2. Make it more simple for the machine to compute it, hence **improve performance**?
3. Reduce the line of codes and follow more the programming Guidelines?

I point this out because for next time would be better to make it more explicit in the question, having said that, as I don't know exactly what you mean, I come up with an answer that more or less covers all of 3 points:

---

### ANSWER

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5tU8isVcqd02ymC2n952LC2Nz_FFPd6NT1lD4crDeSsJi2w/viewform?usp=sf_link'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# ========= < FUNCTION TO GET ALL QUESTION DYNAMICALLY > ========= #
def clean_string_by_id(page, id):

    content = str(page.find(id=id))  # Get Content of page by different ids
    if content != 'None':  # Check if there is actual content or not
        find_question = content.split('>')  # NOTE: Split at tags closing
        if len(find_question) >= 2 and find_question[1][0].isdigit():  # NOTE: If len is 1 means that is not the correct element Also we check if the first element is a digit means that is correct
            cleaned_question = find_question[1].split('.')[1].strip()  # We get the actual Question and strip it already !
            result = cleaned_question.replace('_', '')
            return result
    else:
        return


# ========= < Scan the entire page Dynamically + add result to a list> ========= #
all_questions = []
for i in range(1, 50): # NOTE: I went up to 50 but there may be many more, I let you test it
    get_question = clean_string_by_id(soup, f'i{i}')
    if get_question:  # Append result to list only if there is actual content
        all_questions.append(get_question)

# ========= < show all results > ========= #
for question in all_questions:
    print(question)
```

> **NOTE**

Here I'm assuming that you want to get all elements from this page, hence you don't want to write 2000 variables, as you can see I left the logic basically the same as yours but I wrapped everything in a Function instead.

In fact the steps you follow were pretty good and yes you may "improve it" or make it "smarter" however comprehensible wins complexity. Also take in mind that I **assumed** that get all the 'questions' from that Google Forms was your goal.

---

> EDIT

**As pointed by @wuerfelfreak and as he explains in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65488490/13903942) further improvement can be achived by using [getText()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) function**

Hence here the result of the above function using getText:

```py
def clean_string_by_id(page, id):

    content = page.find(id=id)
    if content:  # NOTE: Check if there is actual content or not, same as if len(content) >= 0
        find_question = content.getText()     # NOTE: Split at tags closing
        if find_question:   # NOTE: same as do if len(findÑ_question) >= 1: ... If is 0 means that is a empty line so we skip it
            cleaned_question = find_question.split('.')[1].strip()  # Same as before
            result = cleaned_question.replace('_', '')
            return result
```

### Documentations & Guides

- [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)
- [getText](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)
- [geeksforgeeks.org | isdigit()](https://www.%C3%A7/python-string-isdigit-application/)

Comment: Nice explanation. I woud still advise on using `.getText` instead of splitting at `">"` for added simplicity.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't realize about this function. BeautifulSoup is a very cool project! I added in my answer